# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor+GetContextType' from assembly 'EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework-6, xaf

I created a new Framework Winforms XAF 21.1.4 Winforms project using EF 6.2

When I tried to enable migrations via Package Manager Console I got

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor+GetContextType' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.AppDomainExecutor.Execute(String operation, Object resultHandler, IDictionary args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.ExecutorBase.InvokeImpl(String operation, IDictionary args)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.ExecutorBase.GetContextType(String contextTypeName, String contextAssemblyName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.MigrationsEnableCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor+GetContextType' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to EF 6.4 via Nuget and was then able to enable-migrations