# ef6.exe throws System.TypeLoadExceptiondepending on environmement

Tags: c#, entity-framework

we are running a code-first app in variuos environment (Test, staging, production). All environments are build with the same process, where the different .config settings for the DB connections are applied with config transform.
Deployment to the various environments is done with a single deployment server with a powershell script. In this deployment script, all pending migrations are run to get the DB up to date.
After an update to EF6, the script has been updated to use ef6.exe instead of migrate.exe.
Now we are experiencing strange behaviour: while the deployment is working for the test environment, the deployment for the staging environment is failing because ef6 throws an exception (see below). Any ideas?
We are deploying identical software where there is only a slight difference in the app.config (different DB servers, different DB names)

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor+Update' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.AppDomainExecutor.Execute(String operation, Object resultHandler, IDictionary args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.ExecutorBase.InvokeImpl(String operation, IDictionary args)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.ExecutorBase.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force, String connectionStringName, String connectionString, String connectionProviderName, String migrationsConfigurationName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.DatabaseUpdateCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor+Update' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Manuall uninstalled migrations on the test environment to have it at the same migration level as staging as i thought it might be some specific migration, but that didn't work

Comment: Would any of these answers help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68451419/system-typeloadexception-could-not-load-type-system-data-entity-infrastructure , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051931/why-is-entity-framework-6-1-3-throwing-a-could-not-load-type-system-data-entit

Comment: Unfortunately not - keep in mind that it is working in one environemnt, but not the other, so it is not in the source code